# How to query kubernetes custom api (networking.gke.io/v1beta1) using go client?

Tags: go, kubernetes

I want to play with kubernetes api with gke. But gke use a special api (networking.gke.io/v1beta1). I want to be able to query it, but the go-client of kubernetes dont have this api. How can I query it?

I try REST API, but dont know at all how to use it, and the documentation is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

GKE networking apis and clients are in this repo : [gke-managed-certs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-managed-certs)

Clients are in this package: [/pkg/clients](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-managed-certs/tree/master/pkg/clients)

Comment: Do you have an exemple of code? I'm not able to understand

Comment: No. You can check the tests to see how clients are used: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-managed-certs/tree/master/e2e